# Getting started with JS and HTML5

Tags: javascript

I'm try to draw  objects  using canvas and JS on HTML5. for that I've 2 file `index.html`  with the follwing :

```
    <html>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
     </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I understood I'm callign here the `script.js` with the following :

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
myCanvas.width = 500;
myCanvas.height = 500;

var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");


function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX,endY);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawArc(ctx, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ctx.stroke();
}
function drawPieSlice(ctx,centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, color ){
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

this.drawLine(_ctx,100,100,200,200);
this.drawArc(_ctx, 150,150,150, 0, Math.PI/3);
this.drawPieSlice(_ctx, 150,150,150, Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 + Math.PI/4, '#ff0000');
```

Opening the `index.html` I can't see a line or an arc, so my question is what I'm missing here ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: You got `_ctx` in your function calls but you defined it as `ctx`.  Could that be it?

Comment: @jmargolisvt  thanks for your comment, I thought I was misunderstanding the call of functions in js ! thank  u !

Comment: @jmargolisvt you can put is as an answer I'll accepted. And to down voter, you're just great

Comment: @Engine Calling the functions with `this.` at the start isn't necessary here; in your code, `this` refers to the `window` object, which is the default context anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `_ctx` in your function calls but you defined it as `ctx`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, you have three options here (listed from what is best to worst imo):

1. use `var _ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");`
   This will fix the code you have, and your functions are reusable for other contexts
2. remove the `ctx` / `_ctx` parameter from your declaration lines and calls
   That way the functions use the existing global variable
3. The suggested solution of changing `_ctx` to `ctx`
   This fixes the code but glosses over the fact that your local `ctx` is shadowing the global one, and that passing the context into the function is unnecessary here; it's the least readable option and bad practice in my personal opinion

There's also a fourth option, one I prefer, but it touches on JavaScript's `prototype`. Declare the function like this:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawLine = function (startX, startY, endX, endY) {
  this.beginPath();
  this.moveTo(startX, startY);
  this.lineTo(endX, endY);
  this.stroke();
}
```

You have now added your own custom function to the browser's API, making it available for all `CanvasRenderingContext2D` objects. You can call it like this:

```
ctx.drawLine(100, 100, 200, 200);
```

Comment: Here's your code, using option #4: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g9jdrunw/

Answer (score 0):

just change `_ctx` to be `ctx`

```
this.drawLine(ctx,100,100,200,200);
this.drawArc(ctx, 150,150,150, 0, Math.PI/3);
this.drawPieSlice(ctx, 150,150,150, Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 + Math.PI/4, '#ff0000');
```

and always check the console tab, because when i tried ur code in the browser got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ctx is not defined` so i changed _ctx to ctx